# Multiscreen Video Player - Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer

I'm considering the development of an Android app designed as a video player. I aim to implement a unique feature allowing users to connect two Android mobile devices. By arranging the devices close to each other horizontally, the video will automatically split into halves. The first device will play the top half of the video, while the second device plays the bottom half, creating a combined screen size resembling that of a foldable device's inside screen.

This feature provides users with an option to enjoy a larger screen for viewing videos by utilizing two devices simultaneously. Furthermore, the audio will play in a synchronized manner. If both devices have stereo speakers, the audio will play in stereo. In the case of devices with a single speaker, users can position them so that each device's speaker points to opposite sides. This setup ensures that each channel in the audio plays through a separate device, creating a stereo effect.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this functionality. The desired outcome is similar to the example provided. Thank you in advance!